# macports over http

Tags: macos, mac, macports

is there an easy way to run mac ports over port 80 (via proxy server)? 873 is blocked. are there any limitations to running this over port 80?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two alternative methods for syncing over HTTP instead of using rsync:

- [Daily tarball](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/PortTreeTarball)
- [Subversion repository](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/SyncingWithSVN)

Both are quite easy to set up, all you need to do is to change a single line in `/opt/local/etc/macports/sources.conf`.

As of version 1.8.0, MacPorts will automatically pick up HTTP and FTP proxy settings from Mac OS X network preferences. You don't need to do anything special anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This may be outdated, but it appers using MacPorts over port 80 requires [a fair amount of work](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-users/2008-February/009129.html).  Basically, it amounts to setting port to use a svn server instead of rsync for the sync process.